# Rails: How to display data obtained from a background task in the home screen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, rake-task, alexa-skills-kit

I have this code to scrape website ranking of `http://example.com/` from [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/example.com)
In `lib/recurring.rb` i have

```
module Recurring
  class MyTask
    include Delayed::RecurringJob
    run_every 1.day
    run_at '12:00pm'
    timezone 'UTC'
    def perform
      url = "http://alexa.com/siteinfo/example.com"
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
      @rank = doc.at_css("strong.metrics-data.align-vmiddle").text
    end
  end
end
```

I have a raketask to execute this in `lib/tasks/my_task.rake`

```
namespace :recurring do
  desc "Get website rank everyday at 12:00 OM UTC"
  task init: :environment do
    #Delete any previously-scheduled recurring jobs
    Delayed::Job.where('(handler LIKE ?)', '--- !ruby/object:Recurring::%').destroy_all

    Recurring::MyTask.schedule!
  end
end
```

when I run

```
$ rake recurring:init
```

the task is executed everyday at 12:00 utc and I have the website rank in `@rank` (line number 10 `recurring.rb`).

But how can I display this data in my index page? I am new to background processing. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Once you save this rank info to the db, it will be autometically reflected in your views . So either the problem is you're not saving the data to db or you don't know how to display it in a view, which is it?

Comment: @Joel_Blum i am not saving the `@rank` to db. is there a way i can get it diplayed without the db being involved

Comment: there's probably no sane choice but saving it to a db, why wouldn't you want to involve a db?

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables are in-memory and are not shared between your rake task and the server. So to pass data from one to the other you need persistence. The database is the standard choice but you could hypothetically use the filesystem, Redis, etc. as well.

Since you added `:environment` to your task you have access to your models (without it, the task is like a standalone Ruby script).

For example:

```
rails g model SiteRanking rank:string
rake db:migrate

# in rake task
SiteRanking.create(rank: @rank)

# in controller
@rank = SiteRanking.last.try(:rank) # will be nil if no record exists
```